# Data is persisting in H2 instead of HSql SpringBoot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, h2, hsqldb

New to Spring boot and embedded db.

In my application.properties file, I have given as,
**spring.datasource.platform=hsqldb**

Unknowingly, **I have used H2 Jar for seeing the Embeded DB Console alone.**

In pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.192</version>
</dependency>
```

And in my configuration file,

```
@Bean
ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = 
        new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
    registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

After running my boot application I've seen that,  table is in H2.

[image]

But in my application.properties, I have given HSql.

I am confused, why I am seeing table in H2. Is that because of H2 package in my pom file?

Curious to know, why it went so.

Could any one give some inputs in this one.

Thx.

Comment: Why do need 2 different in-memory databases in your project? If you need only 1, try remove unnecessary one from pom.

Comment: @Justas: Hi. I wanted to see embedded console. Without knowing much about the db's i tried out. But later, I came to know, it is 2 different DB. But I have provided hsql in the app props, I am curious to know, why it saved the table in the H2 DB. Any idea here?. Thx.

Comment: Try these properties: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:example_db_name;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver